# Listing gvSIG advantages?

Tags: gvsig

Direct comparison between software may not be the best thing to do but as I can't arrive at a conclusion thought of asking here.

Is there any [gvSIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GvSIG) user in this GIS community?

Looking at the [screenshots](http://www.gvsig.org/web/projects/gvsig-desktop/tour/image-gallery-1) gvSIG seems to have lot of features. I particularly liked the single window interface when compared to GRASS. So I wanted to know how gvSIG would suit for image processing and GIS operations in general.

How are the map composing features in gvSIG?

I would also like to know which fares better amongst gvSIG or GRASS for image classification task - particularly digitizing training sites which is improving in GRASS these days(even then working with QGIS is easy for the purpose), ability to handle large rasters and vectors in the process, ease of map composing etc.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking specific questions about software like these.  However, your last question is vague and potentially argumentative.  You can improve that by specifying what you mean by "better": please give the criteria you are interested in.  E.g., are you focusing on breadth of capabilities, or perhaps ability to handle large images, or maybe processing speed, etc.

Comment: You can use GRASS via Sextante in gvSIG, i.e. have the single window interface and more along with the analytical power of GRASS. See http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Sextante

Comment: @markusN, that's great to know. I will check it out.

Comment: @PolyGeo, what's the point of putting a question on hold after ~8 years?! I don't see any value in editing the question since whatever I had to do was done long ago.

Comment: If I saw it 8 years ago I would have voted to place it On Hold.  I saw it today and voted to place it On Hold for the same reason (too broad and too likely to attract opinions). There's no need to edit your question if you are happy for it to remain on the site in its current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [simo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1370/simo), I posted this question onto gvSIG mailing list and got the following answers/links:

This discussion archive can also be read in context at Nabble: [gvSIG advantages](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/gvSIG-advantages-td6398027.html)

---

gvsig uses sextante as raster processing framework.

Take a look at what you can do with it:

http://sextantegis.blogspot.com/,

http://sextante.forge.osor.eu/

Sextante integrates a lot of GRASS algorithms inside (AFAIK you should have GRASS installed for those algorithms to work).

---

Interesting links about gvSIG:

**gvSIG Quickstart:** http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/gvsig_quickstart.html

**gvSIG Courses:** http://www.gvsig.org/web/docusr/learning/gvsig-courses-1#english

**Videos:**
http://www.gvsig.org/web/projects/gvsig-desktop/tour/videos

**User manual:**
https://gvsig.org/web/projects/gvsig-desktop/docs/user/gvsig-desktop-1-11-manual-de-usuario/gvsig-desktop-1-11-manual-de-usuario-en/

---

This review compares some of the various tasks able to be completed by the various leading packages around.

http://gis.fossworkflowguides.com/#external

Answer (score 1):

That's true, it seems there is not much gvSIG users here.

I have no good reply regarding your question but :

- first, you can have a good overview of gvsig features on wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GvSIG#Features_gvSIG_Desktop
- I would give you the advice to browse [gvSIG archives](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/gvSIG-project-f2000051.html) on nabble and maybe to cross-post your question also there! At least, you would meet gvSIG users ;-))

Answer (score 0):

I have found it a little hard to find good documentation on gvSIG. Main development is in spanish so for those of us who are used to english documentation it is a new experience. Quite often the manual are not completely translated.

What I know is that gvSIG forked a while ago and formed gvSIG CE. I dont really know why but it seems that there was some kind of different interests in the use of the oracle spatial driver and how the GUI was designed. I guess that you have to ask Benjamin Ducke of the gvsig ce team if you want to know more. Also SEXTANTE will be removed and replaced from main gvSIG according to the sextante developer Victor Olaya (blogpost at: http://sextantegis.blogspot.se/2011/12/important-notice-for-gvsig-users.html) but I dont know the timeframe for that.

I believe gvSIG will be a better choice if one need more cad functions and tools for geodetic surveying. According to a presentation I found a little while ago (soory, cant find the reference) there will be som kind of connection to totalstations and such.