# QGIS vs gvSIG: Update for 2019

Tags: qgis, comparison, gvsig

There were two posts from back in 2011 about the [advantages of gvSIG](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/gvsig-advantages) and [comparing QGIS and gvSIG](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/qgis-and-gvsig-comparison). It's been 8 years since and I'm wondering if there might be an update since gvSIG and QGIS (at time of writing) are at v2.4 and v3.5, respectively.

Particularly, I'm interested to know what processes one software does better in than the other and how/why so (e.g. for Plugins, QGIS wins hands-down as the community is larger which has led to more plugins being developed).

Outside of the actual technology, I'm also curious as to how the community help has evolved. QGIS has a vast amount of help forums, websites, and tutorials, and I'm wondering if the response of the gvSIG community or if the resources available are equivalent or near equivalent to QGIS.

Comment: A broad and opinion-seeking question like this would be fine to discuss in the GIS Chat Room but is not suitable for the focused Q&A format of the Main site. Those earlier Q&As were asked at a time when the community was still in its infancy and exploring the Stack Exchange format.